# Static member being removed in HttpPost

Tags: c#, controller, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NetCore MVC Controller I am adding a new object (Restaurant) to the static list _restaurantData with the HttpPost Create method below, and then redirecting to the "Details" page of the new Restaurant. While debugging, I can verify that the new restaurant is added to _restaurantData with all the correct properites and the correct id is passed into the RedirectToAction method. Once 'Details' is actually called though, the new Restaurant object has been removed from _restaurantData and so 'model' is null. How could the new restaurant possibly be removed from the list between "Create"'s return statement and the beginning of "Details"? And how could I fix this!

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(RestuarantEditViewModel model)
    {
        var restaurant = new Restaurant();
        restaurant.Name = model.Name;
        restaurant.Cuisine = model.Cuisine;

        _restaurantData.Add(restaurant);

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = restaurant.Id });
    }

    public IActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var model = _restaurantData.Get(id);
        if (model == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is code to add restaurant to list.

```
public void Add(Restaurant newRestaurant)
    {
        newRestaurant.Id = _restaurants.Max(r => r.Id) + 1;
        _restaurants.Add(newRestaurant);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect, the state of the page (and its underlying controller class), is lost, including static variables. What you need to do is save after you have added the new instance:

```
_restaurantData.Add(restaurant);
_restaurantData.SaveChanges(); // Assuming DbContext
```

Then, when your page loads on the Details page, the database will have the model saved and will successfully retrieve it.

If `_restaurantData` is not a `DbContext`, you need it to have some way to save the data between page loads.

Comment: It's not a DbContext, its just a class I made. Is there a way for me to make it save considering that?

Comment: You will have to store the data somewhere because the page state is lost between page loads. Look into Entity Framework and `DbContext`: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/

Comment: Ok. I'm just confused since I've been following a tutorial to the T (which works) yet mine doesn't. Has page state always been lost between page loads or is that new?

Comment: Can you send the link to the tutorial? Maybe I can see what they are doing that saves page state between loads.

Comment: It's on pluralsight, ASP.NET Core 1.0 Fundamentals by Scott Allen [here](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=aspdotnet-core-1-0-fundamentals&author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-core-1-0-fundamentals-m4&clip=4&mode=live). Probably cannot be viewed without an account. I can't find anything in any of the code that saves page state, would it usually be in the controller? _restaurantData is a property of the controller class.

Comment: Yeah, I can't access it. He does cover Entity Framework in the next section. If he shows the code for the controller, see how `_restaurantData` is declared. He may just be creating a `List` in the constructor to use for testing for now.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what he does, create a List in the constructor, and it's what my code does too! Which is why I feel like it should work... I'll definitely be looking into the entity framework, I just don't like not understanding what's going on at the moment :) Thanks for your help though

Comment: He probably has the Id set for the `Restaurant`s in the list preset so that when you navigate to the `Details` page, it uses an `Id` that corresponds to one of the `Id`s set in the `List` he created. That way it finds it and is not `null`.

Comment: He presets 3 restaurants with IDs in the list and then adds a new restaurant with new id in the Add method in RestaurantData (code added to question)